# How to calculate decryption time

Tags: encryption, brute-force

Please I need help with this question. I've been trying to understand how the decryption time works here through an example from my lecture notes. The question is as follows.

> Given a key of length n there are 2<sup>n</sup> possible keys to try in a brute force attack. A key of length 128 bits would require 5,257,322,061,209,440,000,000 years to crack, assuming 8,000,000 guesses/second

I've tried working it out but the result is found wanting.

n = 128, therefore 2<sup>n</sup> will be 2<sup>128</sup> = 3.402823669 x 10<sup>38</sup>

8,000,000 guesses a second for a year should give `8,000,000 * 365 * 24 * 3600` 
therefore guesses per year = 2.52288 x 10<sup>14</sup>

But the main problem is that the guesses when divided by total guesses in a year do not give an accurate answer.

I'm guessing `time it takes to decrypt` = `total length` / `guesses` which is:

`3.402823669 x 10^38`/`2.52288 x 10^14` = `1.348785384 * 10^24`

but the answer says it would require `5.257322061 x 10^21`

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but if you divide the expected answer by your answer, you get 256.55.  I wonder if somewhere along the lines, there was a confusion between bits and bytes and the fact that `2^8 =256`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkLakata I thought so as well but I decided to stick with my Lecturer's specification. I can't say he doesn't know the difference between bits and bytes.

Comment: Being pedantic I would say `Given a key of length n there are **up to**  2^n possible keys to try in a brute force attack`.  If you are lucky you may guess the same number I have on my luggage.